# C# Excel input concatenate two columns

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have been struggling to find an answer to this. I am importing an Excel spreadsheet into C# using Oledb. This works fine, however while importing I wish to join two of the Excel columns together i.e concatenate them.

This is the code I currently have:

```
string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes;\";";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select [ID], [Subject], [Catalog], [Last], [First Name], [Descr], [Mark] from[" + textBox2.Text + "$]", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

The code above is working fine. The two columns I wish to join are Subject and Catalog and for this to be called Module. Subject is a string of three letters and Catalog four numbers. Is there a way to do this within the select statement or an alternative method?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `OleDbAdapter` query like this:

```
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select [ID], [Subject] + ' ' + [Catalog] AS [Module], [Last], [First Name], [Descr], [Mark] from[" + textBox2.Text + "$]", conn);
```

Notice that `[Subject] + ' ' + [Catalog] AS [Module]` are combined into a single string and placed under *Module* alias.

Answer (score 0):

You can "CONCAT" in the query:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh231515(v=sql.120).aspx

```
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select [ID], CONCAT( [Subject], [Catalog] ) AS subject_catalog, [Last], [First Name], [Descr], [Mark] from[" + textBox2.Text + "$]", conn);
```